# What does "though" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

"I have been waiting for your reply.You don't reply, tho. "

I do not understand the above sentence and the usage of "though".

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to the previous sentence, and the meaning of ***[though](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/though)***  in this  case most likely is:

> despite this:
>
> - *We went to high school together. I haven't seen her for years, though.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: At  the end of the sentence though does not mean despite this.

Comment: It is not the most likely meaning at all. If it were, you would be able to substitute despite this other than awkwardly in that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"I have been waiting for your reply.You don't reply, though. " means:

"I have been waiting for your reply. But you don't reply."

**Though** is used to mean **but** in spoken language. It can be placed at the beginning or at the end of the sentence  when used like this.

More examples:
I called him at five. He didn't answer the phone, though.

They came over in the afternoon. They did not enjoy themselves, though.

Though there means but, not despite.

Despite is:

Though he worked hard, he had no success.=
Despite working hard, he had no success.

EDIT:
The Cambridge Dictionary example meaning **but** can be  transformed placing the **though** at the end where it continues to mean **but**

*We didn’t make any profit though nobody knows why*.= *We didn't make any profit*. 
*Nobody knows why, though*.

And my example: I have been waiting for your reply.You don't reply, though.= I have been waiting for your reply **but** you don't reply.

So, the **but** meaning requires **though** in the middle as the dictionary states **or** **you need two sentences with though at the end of the second sentence.**

Comment: Excuse me, but in your sentence 
"I have been waiting for your reply.You don't reply, though. "  means “despite the fact that Ive been waiting for your reply , you don’t reply”...or nor?

Comment: OK: I called him at five. He didn't answer the phone, though. They came over in the afternoon. They did not enjoy themselves, though. That is not despite. It is ***but***. Despite is: Though I worked hard, I had no success. Despite working hard, I had no success.

Comment: Hi @Lambie. I want to ask something if possible. When the "though" is used like "but", does it have to be at some place in the sentence? Because Cambrdige says: "When the although/though clause comes after a main clause, it can also mean ‘but' ". And in the examples of the dictionary, "though" is always placed in the middle of two clause. (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/dilbilgisi/ingiliz-dilbilgisi/although-or-though?q=though). But as your examples show, "though" can be at the end of the other clause.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden See my edit. Notice: two sentences with though at the end of the second one.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for clarification. I think this is important for writing not for speaking + When "though" is used at the end of a sentence, does it has to be mean "but" ? Could it mean "despite" when it is used at the end?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden No, it is spoken,not written, in fact. Do not make me repeat myself. My comments are very clear. "despite"**can never be at the end of a sentence. And please stop doing this. I answer your question, and then you ask the same question again. Please don't do that.

Comment: Hi, @Lambie again me. Could I ask one more question on this issue?  I often see "though" used at the beginning of one seperate sentence. I suppose it is used to mean "but". I am not sure if this usage is okay. For example: " ...I think they are more or less equivalent, but "help with" sounds a lot more natural in the present day. (***Though*** I wouldn't be surprised if there is some regional variation with this) " (Source:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63994/help-on-with-something)

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Though he likes her, he will not call her. [though: other usage, written, meaning despite]. BUT: "Though I wouldn't be surprised if there is some regional variation with this." is **a verbal response to someone else**. In those cases, the **though** can go at the beginning or the end.  "I wouldn't be surprised if there is some regional variation with this, though."